# Usign Python: Dictionary of company management is given, Generate a function using recursion to get printout as below

Tags: recursion

Python

company = {"name":"George", "manages":[{"name":"James", "manages":[{"name":"Jill"},{"name":"Jenny"}]}, {"name":"Jamila", "manages":[{"name":"Jewel"}, {"name":"Jasmine"}, {"name":"Jeremey"}]}]}

George runs a company. He manages James and Jamila, who each have a small team to manage. In James' team are Jill and Jenny. In Jamila's team are Jewel, Jasmine and Jeremy.

Result should be:

George is at level 1
James is at level 2
Jill is at level 3
Jenny is at level 3
Jamila is at level 2
Jewel is at level 3
Jasmine is at level 3
Jeremey is at level 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1o1Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1SFw.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```js
function* levels({ name, manages = [] }, level = 1) {
  yield [name, level]
  for (const m of manages)
    yield *levels(m, level + 1)
}

const company = {"name":"George", "manages":[{"name":"James", "manages":[{"name":"Jill"},{"name":"Jenny"}]}, {"name":"Jamila", "manages":[{"name":"Jewel"}, {"name":"Jasmine"}, {"name":"Jeremey"}]}]}

for (const [name, level] of levels(company))
  console.log(`${name} is at level ${level}`)
```

```
George is at level 1
James is at level 2
Jill is at level 3
Jenny is at level 3
Jamila is at level 2
Jewel is at level 3
Jasmine is at level 3
Jeremey is at level 3
```

For python the answer is nearly identical

```py
from json import loads

def levels(node, level = 1):
  yield (node['name'], level)
  try:
    for m in node['manages']:
      yield from levels(m, level + 1)
  except KeyError:
    return

company = loads('{"name":"George", "manages":[{"name":"James", "manages":[{"name":"Jill"},{"name":"Jenny"}]}, {"name":"Jamila", "manages":[{"name":"Jewel"}, {"name":"Jasmine"}, {"name":"Jeremey"}]}]}')

for (name, level) in levels(company):
  print(f"{name} is at level {level}")
```

```
George is at level 1
James is at level 2
Jill is at level 3
Jenny is at level 3
Jamila is at level 2
Jewel is at level 3
Jasmine is at level 3
Jeremey is at level 3
```

Comment: How can it be modified for Python?

Comment: Thank you very much for you wonderful answer, however I am a beginner and I need the answer in Python.
In what language is it written?

Comment: I start getting errors after 3 lines. I have attached an image.

Comment: I use Python 3.9.7. It seems the syntax you use is a bit different from what I use. so I modified a little bit

Comment: instead of node.name and node.manages, I wrote node['name'] and node['manages'].
then still I get until third line.
George is at level 1
James is at level 2
Jill is at level 3
and errors...

Comment: Can you please put python code in code snippet? so that I can see it runs smooth.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @JamesLi sorry about that, I had a few of my wires crossed with the dict access syntax. The snippet is copy/paste/runnable now